# Retrieve buckets with python on GCP virtual machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use Python3 on a GCP virtual machine (not in local machine). I need to extract data from a certain bucket. This is the code i'm using:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = timetables-new/23/00_H0.json
bucket = client.get_bucket("bucket_name")
```

It returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client
.py", line 301, in get_bucket
    bucket.reload(client=self)
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/_helpe
rs.py", line 130, in reload
    _target_object=self,
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", lin
e 393, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/timetables-new/23/00_H0.json?projection=noAcl: Not Found
```

How can i retrieve the file, so i can use it in my python script?

Edit:
Since i was using an object name as bucket name (/ not allowed) i also tried:

```
bucket_name = timetables-new
```

Which is the name of the entire bucket, but i have the same error.

Comment: You are using an `object` name for the `bucket` name.

Comment: That's correct, thanks for pointing it out. I ran the same commands using `bucket_name = folder/23/` , `bucket_name = folder/23` , `bucket_name = folder/` , `bucket_name = folder` but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Update your question and error messages with the actual bucket name that you are using. Verify that the bucket exists first and that you have permission to access it (IAM Storage Role).

Comment: While i check permission access, the real name of the filename i'm trying to retrieve is (full path) `timetables-new/23/00_H0.json`

Comment: Edit your question and update with real information for all parts. Do not post details in comments. By posting comments you make the details unclear and we won't spend the time to track the question and updates in the comments.

Comment: Once again - You are using an object name for the bucket name. A bucket does not have `/` in its name.

Comment: I tried with the bucket name only (see edit) without success. Maybe it's a permission problem, i'm trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that is missing from you post is how you are actually authenticating. You may need to set the json key of service account as follows:

`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key.json`

Answer (score 0):

try to use Gcsfuse of Gsutil, it goes something like this :

- gsutil lets you copy files from the bucket to your virtual machine :

```
gsutil -m cp gs://name_of_bucket/.../file destination/path/on/your/VM
```

- Whereas gcsfuse creates a symbolic link to allow to access files in the bucket :

```
mkdir /path/to/mount
gcsfuse bucket_name /path/to/mount
```